# How can I cite Intel developer manual?

Tags: citations

I'm trying to cite [Intel Developer Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). I'm a bit confused how should I cite it? Should I cite the Whole website with the link and access date? Or Should I cite a particular chapter that I used? What is the correct approach with BibTeX?

Comment: You cite it like anything else, by its title, its author, its publication date, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bibliography, you can cite a manual as a publication, e.g.,

Intel (2016) *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*, Volume 2 (2A, 2B, 2C & 2D).

In the main body, cite the relevant chapters, e.g., `\cite[Chapter~3]{IntelManual}`. Use the `@manual` tag in your BibTex file.